# How to uninstall an app completely from android(to solve signature errors)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am developing an app from so many days and i use my phone to test the app. So android studio always installs my app in my phone directly through ADB.

Today i made a signed apk from android studio and when i tried to install it. It gave me an error "App not installed - an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed"

Check This Image :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumOm.png

So i uninstalled the old app and when i tried to install the signed apk it gave me error again"App not installed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think my old app still left some Data in my phone.

So i used Titanium BackUp Manager and in first removed the app data and then uninstalled the old app.

This solved the problem and i was able to install my new app now.

Any,Other suggestions are welcome ??

Comment: Interesting, usually this isnt a problem and just uninstalling works

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the signature by removing /system/app/ folder from the device.
I also had issues installing gcam ports on my android device.
The above solution worked for me and I was able to install the app after removing
/system/app/GoogleCameraLegacy folder through TWRP recovery.